# ForkJoinFramework with AtomicLong is not giving consistent result

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join, atomicinteger

I'm trying to play with ForkJoinFramework. I know that my code might not be a good use case to use ForkJoin, but it should work at least..

I'm using RecursiveAction to concurrently modify a static AtomicLong variable. But I'm having some issues there, the result is not correct and not consistent.(Everytime I run it, the result is different).

I'm assuming AtomicLong is thread-safe, so the only thing that might be a reason would be some tasks are lost. But why?

`

```
public class ForkJoinFramework {

    private static AtomicLong sum = new AtomicLong(0);
    static class MyTask extends RecursiveAction {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        int left;
        int right;
        MyTask(int left, int right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
        @Override
        protected void compute() {
            if(right - left < 100) {
                for(int i = left; i < right; i++) {
                    sum.getAndIncrement();
                }
            } else {
                ForkJoinTask<Void> leftTask = new MyTask(left, left + (right - left) / 2).fork();
                ForkJoinTask<Void> rightTask = new MyTask(left + (right - left) / 2 + 1, right).fork();
                leftTask.join();
                rightTask.join();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyTask myTask = new MyTask(0, 10000000);
        myTask.compute();
        System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum.get());
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error.  In your `for` loop, you are not counting the value of `right`, so if e.g. `left` is 101 and `right` is 150, you increment only 49 times.

The value I consistently get is `9868929`, because you must be splitting the task into separate `ForkJoinTask`s `10000001` - `9868929`, or `131072`, or 2<sup>17</sup>, which makes sense as a power of 2 based on your algorithm.

Change

```
for(int i = left; i < right; i++) {
```

to

```
for(int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
```

and you'll get `10000001`, and if you want `10000000`, start with `1` instead of `0`.

There's nothing wrong with losing tasks or the consistency of `AtomicLong`; you just had an off-by-one error.

Comment: Thank you  for the answer! Yeah it's consistent.